# How to Delete Carbon Copy Recipients

Tags: docusignapi

I know how to delete signers from an envelope, but how can I delete carbon copy recipients from an envelope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly can. There is an API call to delete recipients from an in process envelope. Documentation (REST API) available here: https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Delete%20Recipients%20from%20an%20Envelope.htm?Highlight=delete%20recipient